# Parsing newline delimited JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json, newline

How can I go about achieving this with PHP? Any decoding returns a null value. Can someone show me an example of how to split each line and decode each line?

JSON: https://codeshare.io/2BD4ma

Added some code:

```
$jsonFile = file_get_contents('feeds/quotes.json');

$str = $jsonFile;
$arr = explode("\n", $str);


foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    // $arr[3] will be updated with each value from $arr...
    echo "{$key} => {$value} ";
}
```

How can I grab the values of each here?

Comment: You did not give any example, so we can't help you

Comment: Without any sample input or output or example, its difficult to help you.

Comment: what is a "newline delimited JSON"? never heard of it? how does it look like?

Comment: added to the original post. I'm trying to follow this post, but don't really understand the code fully and it doesn't work in my case: http://importio.desk.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2471525-json-response  I also don't have any access to npm or node on my server :(

Comment: I'm not sure what else I am missing here?

Comment: why don't you just use the [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function?

Comment: decode returns NULL.

Comment: Would love to see how it is done using decode. I'm not so sure decode recognizes it and just renders it invalid?

Comment: Someone seems to have messed up the codeshare link. Any chance we can get the actual JSON in the question?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not relevant for OP anymore, but if anyone else ends up here, the following is my solution to processing [newline-delimited JSON streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_streaming) efficiently.

```php
// The buffer holds all currently un-parsed output; it will never grow
// beyond a handful of records to keep the memory usage low.
$buffer = '';

// We assume $data is another generator we read the data from. If it
// isn't, you can simply unwrap the iteration and do $buffer = $data.
// Note that a chunk may vary in length and isn't split at any special
// position, so we can't rely on a chunk to be valid JSON here.
foreach ($data as $chunk) {

    // Append the whole chunk to the current read buffer, so any
    // incomplete line in the previous chunk will be completed now.
    $buffer .= $chunk;

    // We work on a stream of JSON objects with a line break as the
    // delimiter. Therefore, we can simply iterate the read buffer
    // as long as we have line breaks, and decode every line as a JSON
    // object individually.
    while (str_contains($buffer, '}' . PHP_EOL)) {

        // { "foo": "bar" }\n{ "foo": "baz" }
        // ^--------------^ <-- take this part
        $payload = substr(
            $buffer,
            0,
            strpos($buffer, '}' . PHP_EOL) + 1
        );

        // { "foo": "bar" }\n{ "foo": "baz" }
        // ^----------------^ <-- remove this part from the buffer
        $buffer = substr($buffer, strlen($payload));

        if ( ! $payload) {
            continue;
        }

        // Yield the next object. That way, the memory usage will be
        // as minimal as possible.
        try {
            yield json_decode(
                $payload,
                true,
                512,
                JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR
            );
        } catch (JsonException $exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                'Could not read next record: ' .
                $exception->getMessage() . ': ' .
                $payload
            );
        }
    }
}
```

The general idea is:

1. Buffer input chunks until we find an end marker, that is: a closing curly brace followed by a newline
2. Take and remove the object JSON and the delimiter from the buffer
3. Parse and yield the object
4. Continue as long as there are end markers in the input

As this is implemented using [generators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php), the code can process unlimited amounts of data without using more than a few KBs of memory.